# Possible to cache Google Analytic requests?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, google-api, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to force a date when sending events (of any type) to Google Analytics? I'm looking into making a desktop App that sends usage to Google Analytics (requested by the customer himself), but the app will get internet connection just once or twice per week.

It's clear that if I cache the events and send them whenever possible, they will show in the GA site as being produced when I sent them instead of when they really happened, so I need to know if the API supports specifying the date (and timestamp if possible) of each event, but haven't found anything so far.

I don't specify any client implementation, because I'm not using one in particular, I don't know which one is considered superior. If this isn't supported at all, the implementation doesn't matter, otherwise, I could always hack it around or something.

EDIT: I've seen that when calling utm.gif, the utmcc parameter has 3 time related values (using EPOCH time), but I don't know if modifying these values will allow me to achieve what I seek.

I've also seen the Measurement protocol that I don't know if it's something I should look into...

Lastly, I'll repeat just in case this is a requested by the client, not something I decided to do by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, this use case is not supported right now.

The Measurement protocol is what you'd want to use and there is a way to send latent hits using the [Queue Time](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt) parameter. However, the documentation says that anything sent beyond 4 hours will probably not get processed.

Comment: D'oh, so that's what I feared. I wonder which underlying calls are made by the mobile apps using the Google Analytics, although it may be irrelevant since they are created separately in the GA site.